# Is there is any way to check that a song is copyrighted in YT Music by someone using the youtube api v3 and python?

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am trying to create a python application which can retrieve a copyright info if a song is inserted inside it.

I don't know how to start and from which section in youtube API docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve info about copyright with Python via the YouTube API. Look for `contentDetails.licensedContent`. See [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.licensedContent) to learn more.

From the docs:

> boolean: Indicates whether the video represents licensed content, which means that the content was uploaded to a channel linked to a YouTube content partner and then claimed by that partner.